# O que é uma classe wrapper?

Tags: php, c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, design-pattern

**O que é uma classe wrapper?**

**Como elas podem ser úteis?**

Citar exemplos de uso em [php](/questions/tagged/php) ou [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), bem como quando se deve usar ou não.

Comment: Esta pergunta não está genérica demais?

Comment: É literalmente uma classe que embrulha outra.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrapper são classes cuja as funcionalidades que expoem estão implementadas em outro lugar.

É comum em C# por exemplo criarmos classes wrappers para expor funcionalidades da API Win32 que são embutidas no Framework .NET através da funcionalidade chamada PInvoke.

Você pode ter também Wrappers que expoem funcionalidade de outras bibliotecas e isso acontece muito em PHP. Um exemplo é a biblioteca phpGTK que contem diversas classes wrappers da biblioteca nativa.

É recomendado o uso de classes wrappers quando você precisa integrar funcionalidade de bibliotecas/runtimes/linguagens externas a que você está utilizando pois elas te fornecem uma interface nativa a sua linguagem para os clientes do seu código. Além disso concentrando em um lugar só a possível manutenção que você precisará realizar caso uma nova versão da biblioteca externa seja incompatível com a integração que foi realizada.